# Image upload application for Twitter and TwitPic-Oauth necessary?

Tags: actionscript-3, twitter, air, oauth-2.0

Having problems simply uploading images to twitpic

I keep getting a fail response even though my username and password are correct.
Is this because that now to upload images to twitpic(and I assume Twitter) you MUST use Oauth?

```
 <err code="1001" msg="Invalid twitter username or password" />
```

This is the sample code I am using

```
package 
{
    import flash.events.DataEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.filesystem.File;
    import flash.net.FileFilter;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
    import flash.net.URLVariables;

    public class TwitPic
    {
        private var _file:File;

        public function TwitPic()
        {
            _file = new File();
            _file.addEventListener(DataEvent.UPLOAD_COMPLETE_DATA,uploadCompleteDataHandler);
            browse();
        }
        private function browse():void {
            _file.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, fileSelected);
            _file.browse( new Array( new FileFilter( "Images (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.gif, *.png)", "*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png" ) ) );
        }

        private function fileSelected(event:Event):void {
            var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://twitpic.com/api/upload");

            // The API requires the request be sent via POST
            urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

            // Enter a valid Twitter username / password combination
            var urlVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
            urlVars.username = TWITTER_USERNAME;
            urlVars.password = TWITTER_PASSWORD;
            urlRequest.data = urlVars;

            // The API requires the file be labeled as 'media'
            _file.upload(urlRequest, 'media');
        }

        private function uploadCompleteDataHandler(event:DataEvent):void
        {
            var resultXML:XML = new XML(event.text);

            // Trace the path to the resulting image tiny url (mediaurl)
            trace(resultXML.child("mediaurl")[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I read the doc and your request have missing arguments for both API. If you're using the V1 API you need to pass APP ID and other information. The V2 API use OAuth.

[V1 upload documentation](http://dev.twitpic.com/docs/1/upload/)

[V2 upload documentation](http://dev.twitpic.com/docs/2/upload/)

Comment: thanks but BOTH V1 and V2 use Oauth. My question is whether Oauth is absolutely necessary to upload image data.